# Keras and GPU useage

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, keras

I am using keras 1.1.0 with Theano backend. In order to use GPU I set the os.envorn as:

```
os.environ['THEANO_FLAGS'] = "device=gpu0"
```

before importing keras. Importing keras gives me the following message:

```
Using gpu device 0: TITAN X (Pascal) (CNMeM is disabled, cuDNN 5105)
/home/library_python/lib/python/Theano-0.8.2-py2.7.egg/theano/sandbox/cuda/__init__.py:600: UserWarning: Your cuDNN version is more recent than the one Theano officially supports. If you see any problems, try updating Theano or downgrading cuDNN to version 5.
  warnings.warn(warn)
```

So I thought I was setting the device correctly. However, when I train the model with keras, nvidia-smi shows the following message:

```
Fri May  5 13:05:33 2017
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.51                 Driver Version: 375.51                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 730      On   | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 30%   38C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     56MiB /   980MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  TITAN X (Pascal)    On   | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 36%   63C    P2    87W / 250W |    373MiB / 12189MiB |     35%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  TITAN X (Pascal)    On   | 0000:03:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   42C    P8    18W / 250W |      3MiB / 12189MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
|    1      1520    C   /usr/bin/python                                155MiB |
|    1     14996    C   python                                         215MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It says I am only using 215MB of GPU memory. I was expecting more like 10GB of usage. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? Is my setting for the GPU device correct?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved after changing the Theano_flag as:

```
os.environ['THEANO_FLAGS'] = "device=gpu0,floatX=float32,lib.cnmem=1"
```

Now I am using 11.7G memory as expected.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.51                 Driver Version: 375.51                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 730      On   | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 30%   38C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     56MiB /   980MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  TITAN X (Pascal)    On   | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 28%   47C    P2    78W / 250W |  11923MiB / 12189MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  TITAN X (Pascal)    On   | 0000:03:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   42C    P8    18W / 250W |      3MiB / 12189MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
|    1      1520    C   /usr/bin/python                                155MiB |
|    1     15543    C   python                                       11765MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It is advisable to clip cnmem to `0.95`.

Comment: Actually, may I ask what exactly cnmem=1 doing?

Comment: It basically pre-allocates the GPU memory. It is [observed](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13381/how-does-the-cnmem-library-work-and-which-types-of-theano-models-does-it-speed) that setting `cnmem` gives speed improvements. However, you would not want to block all memory of GPU, so the convention is to clip it at `0.95`.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever decide to use tensorflow, you can do it like this:

```
#Take advantage of GPU for parallel processing, but grow as needed
cfg = tf.ConfigProto()
cfg.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(session_config=cfg)
```